# Upload multiple files from S3 to Frame IO

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, frame

On file upload in S3, I am triggering lambda function which will generate s3 url and create file in Frame IO. Whenever I am trying to upload many files at once in S3, file is not creating properly in Frame IO and throwing Preview Unsupported Error (for mp4 files which is supported by default). To fix this issue, I tried to use index as a request parameter which worked out only on 2 or 3 files upload. If I am trying to upload more files, the same error arise. Please find the lambda function code below

```
import requests
import boto3
import json
import urllib.parse
import mimetypes
from botocore.config import Config
import os

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', config = Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
client = boto3.client('ssm')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    if not key.endswith('/'):
        if key.find('/') >= 0:
            temp_key = key.rsplit('/', 1)
            key = temp_key[1]
        print(key)
        size = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['size']
        frameioIndex = int(client.get_parameter(Name='/frameio/asset/index_Dev')['Parameter']['Value']) - 1
        print(frameioIndex)
        s3_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url("get_object", Params={"Bucket": bucket, "Key": key})
        response = requests.post(os.environ['FRAMEIO_BASE_API_URL'] + "assets" + "/" + os.environ['FRAMEIO_PROJECT_ID'] + "/" + "children",data=json.dumps({"type": "file","name": key,"filesize": size,"filetype": mimetypes.guess_type(key)[0],"source": {"url": s3_url},"index": frameioIndex}), headers={"Authorization":"Bearer " + os.environ['FRAMEIO_TOKEN'], "Content-type": "application/json"}) client.put_parameter(Name='/frameio/asset/index_Dev',Value=str(frameioIndex),Type='String',Overwrite=True)
        print(response)
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps('Successfully uploaded the asset!')
        }
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Uploaded object is not a file!')
    }
```

Comment: **Side-note:** Amazon S3 might send _multiple_ events to the Lambda function, but your code is only processing the _first_ record (`event['Records'][0]`). You should use a loop to process all records, eg `for record in event['Records']: bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']` etc.

Comment: Actually, on multiple file upload, lambda function is getting triggered individually for each file. Because of this, there is only one record in event.

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved by changing variable name 'key' to 'filename' in line number 14 (key = temp_key[1]) and used filename in requests API. The above issue occurred as I tried to override the filename and passing it to generate_presigned_url method to generate s3 url.